# Hello! How can i use GPU servers on GCP?

Tags: google-compute-engine

How can i use GPU servers on GCP ?
a could not create new GPU app .

Somebody had this trouble before ?

[image: quota exceeded image here]

Comment: At first glance an error message *"quota exceeded"*  suggests that you start by looking at your current quota - https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas

Answer (score 0):

As what @Rob stated on your error message having Quota exceeded limit you can refer to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas).

You can try to select a different region and create NVIDIA_T4_GPUS for your VM instance and refer to this document for [GPU regions and zones availability](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/gpus/gpu-regions-zones).

If you still have the same issue you can try to [contact sales](https://cloud.google.com/contact/) for higher quota eligibility.